# Image uploading issue using blueimp jquery file upload plugin in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, file-upload, blueimp

I have downloaded blueimp jquery file upload plugin example in C# and when running the program I am getting error and unable to upload whatever the filesize maybe.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance.

Here is the result:

[image]

Here is the aspx code:

```
    <div id="fileupload">
    <form action="Upload.ashx" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="fileupload-buttonbar">
        <label class="fileinput-button">
            <span>Add files...</span>
            <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple="multiple" />
        </label>
        <%-- <button type="submit" class="start">Start upload</button>
        <button type="reset" class="cancel">Cancel upload</button> --%>
        <button type="button" class="delete">
            Delete all files</button>
        <div class="fileupload-progressbar">
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
    <div class="fileupload-content">
        <table class="files">
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the Upload.ashx code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.AccessControl;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

namespace jQueryUploadTest {
    public class Upload : IHttpHandler {
        public class FilesStatus {
            public string thumbnail_url { get; set; }
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string url { get; set; }
            public int size { get; set; }
            public string type { get; set; }
            public string delete_url { get; set; }
            public string delete_type { get; set; }
            public string error { get; set; }
            public string progress { get; set; }
        }
        private readonly JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        private string ingestPath;
        public bool IsReusable { get { return false; } }
        public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
            var r = context.Response;
            ingestPath = @"C:\temp\ingest\";

            r.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
            r.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "private, no-cache");

            HandleMethod(context);
        }

        private void HandleMethod (HttpContext context) {
            switch (context.Request.HttpMethod) {
                case "HEAD":
                case "GET":
                    ServeFile(context);
                    break;

                case "POST":
                    UploadFile(context);
                    break;

                case "DELETE":
                    DeleteFile(context);
                    break;

                default:
                    context.Response.ClearHeaders();
                    context.Response.StatusCode = 405;
                    break;
            }
        }

        private void DeleteFile (HttpContext context) {
            var filePath = ingestPath + context.Request["f"];
            if (File.Exists(filePath)) {
                File.Delete(filePath);
            }
        }

        private void UploadFile (HttpContext context) {
            var statuses = new List<FilesStatus>();
            var headers = context.Request.Headers;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(headers["X-File-Name"])) {
                UploadWholeFile(context, statuses);
            } else {
                UploadPartialFile(headers["X-File-Name"], context, statuses);
            }


            WriteJsonIframeSafe(context, statuses);
        }

        private void UploadPartialFile (string fileName, HttpContext context, List<FilesStatus> statuses) {
            if (context.Request.Files.Count != 1) throw new HttpRequestValidationException("Attempt to upload chunked file containing more than one fragment per request");
            var inputStream = context.Request.Files[0].InputStream;
            var fullName = ingestPath + Path.GetFileName(fileName);

            using (var fs = new FileStream(fullName, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write)) {
                var buffer = new byte[1024];

                var l = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, 1024);
                while (l > 0) {
                    fs.Write(buffer,0,l);
                    l = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, 1024);
                }
                fs.Flush();
                fs.Close();
            }

            statuses.Add(new FilesStatus {
                thumbnail_url = "Thumbnail.ashx?f=" + fileName,
                url = "Upload.ashx?f=" + fileName,
                name = fileName,
                size = (int)(new FileInfo(fullName)).Length,
                type = "image/png",
                delete_url = "Upload.ashx?f=" + fileName,
                delete_type = "DELETE",
                progress = "1.0"
            });

        }

        private void UploadWholeFile(HttpContext context, List<FilesStatus> statuses) {
            for (int i = 0; i < context.Request.Files.Count; i++) {
                var file = context.Request.Files[i];
                file.SaveAs(ingestPath + Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));
                var fname = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                statuses.Add(new FilesStatus
                             {
                                thumbnail_url = "Thumbnail.ashx?f=" + fname,
                                url = "Upload.ashx?f=" + fname,
                                name = fname,
                                size = file.ContentLength,
                                type = "image/png",
                                delete_url = "Upload.ashx?f=" + fname,
                                delete_type = "DELETE",
                                progress = "1.0"
                             });
            }
        }

        private void WriteJsonIframeSafe(HttpContext context, List<FilesStatus> statuses) {
            context.Response.AddHeader("Vary", "Accept");
            try {
                if (context.Request["HTTP_ACCEPT"].Contains("application/json")) {
                    context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                } else {
                    context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
                }
            } catch {
                context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            }

            var jsonObj = js.Serialize(statuses.ToArray());
            context.Response.Write(jsonObj);
        }

        private void ServeFile (HttpContext context) {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Request["f"])) ListCurrentFiles(context);
            else DeliverFile(context);
        }

        private void DeliverFile (HttpContext context) {
            var filePath = ingestPath + context.Request["f"];
            if (File.Exists(filePath)) {
                context.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
                context.Response.WriteFile(filePath);
                context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment, filename=\"" + context.Request["f"] + "\"");
            } else {
                context.Response.StatusCode = 404;
            }
        }

        private void ListCurrentFiles (HttpContext context) {
            var files = new List<FilesStatus>();

            var names = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\temp\ingest", "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

            foreach (var name in names) {
                var f = new FileInfo(name);
                files.Add(new FilesStatus
                {
                    thumbnail_url = "Thumbnail.ashx?f=" + f.Name,
                    url = "Upload.ashx?f=" + f.Name,
                    name = f.Name,
                    size = (int)f.Length,
                    type = "image/png",
                    delete_url = "Upload.ashx?f=" + f.Name,
                    delete_type = "DELETE"
                });
            }

            context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline, filename=\"files.json\"");
            var jsonObj = js.Serialize(files.ToArray());
            context.Response.Write(jsonObj);
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set **url : 'Upload.ashx'** parameter in your application.js when fileupload function is called.

Cordialy

Toregua

Answer (score 0):

You can actually remove the FORM from your aspx page, but then you want to move your call to the .fileupload initialization.

I believe you are working with the same example I am, but even if you are not you should find some code that looks like:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({

});
```

but then you will want to change that to this

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
  url:'Upload.ashx'
});
```

Hope this helps.